# How to scale an image inside a container

Tags: css, image, background

Hey guys I have been running into this problem where I create a container box but the image I put inside is either being stretch or some parts of the image is not showing up

I've tried to make the box bigger at that works to some extent but it is still cutting off parts of the image. I have also tried object-fit but it doesn't seem to work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Example-1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Example.css" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="img-box">
      <div class="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

```css
.img-box {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px grey;
  background: url(about.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I expected the image to scale when I used object-fit but it doesn't seem to be the case. Any ideas?

Comment: For this, you have to make sure that the image in the background is of the same ratio as it's container.

Answer (score 0):

use width:100% to prevent the stretched images, and below code may you on second case.

```
.img-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px grey;
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/32/Flag_of_Pakistan.svg/800px-Flag_of_Pakistan.svg.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.text{
  height:100%
}
```